# Feature Builder multiple projects and parameters

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I am using Visual Studio Feature Builder to create a new Guidance in my office. Everything was working fine until I smashed my head against the multiple project template.
When you create a multiple project template it looks like there is now way to propagate parameters value in the child project of the template solution.
Any idea or tutorial or whatever as I am going mad with this.

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, want to retrieve some value that is available within the template substitution dictionary, you can do this by adding a binding/command combination to the BeforeUnfold property of your VSTemplateLaunchPoint.

When the command executes, you can inspect the TemplateReplacementsDictionary which is available by accessing FeatureCallContext.Current.TemplateReplacementsDictionary.

The value of this variable is not valid in the AfterUnfold situation.  However, you can access the Blackboard inside the command you bind to BeforeUnfold if you wish to save user inputs.

The same dictionary should be used for all projects in your multi-project template.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I do but unfortunately it doesn't work (the replacement dictionary) in the child .vstemplate file. The replacement happens only into the root .vstemplate file.